# Too many arguments, expected arguments "command"

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to run a custom command through the terminal, but keep getting the error: Too many arguments, expected arguments "command".

When searching for similar issues all i've been able to find was people using the scheduler, and nothing about calling the command from terminal.

The signature for the command i'm trying to run is:

```
class MigrateSiteMysiteCommand extends Command
{
protected $signature = 'migrate:site:mysite.dk {--from=} {--to=}';
...
```

And then i use php artisan help migrate:site:mysite.dk i get this:

```
Usage:
migrate:site:mysite.dk [options]

Options:
   --from[=FROM]
   --to[=TO]
-h,--help            Display this help message
-q,--quiet           Do not output any message
-V,--version         Display this application version
   --ansi            Force ANSI output
   --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
-n,--no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
   --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
-v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose 
output and 3 for debug
```

I've tried running the command in different ways formatting the arguments, but get the same error either way:

php artisan migrate:site:mysite.dk --from=2019-02-27 16:22:10 --to=2019-02-28 23:59:59

php artisan migrate:site:mysite.dk --from='2019-02-27 16:22:10' --to='2019-02-28 23:59:59'

php artisan migrate:site:mysite.dk --from '2019-02-27 16:22:10' --to '2019-02-28 23:59:59'

php artisan migrate:site:mysite.dk --from 2019-02-27 16:22:10 --to 2019-02-28 23:59:59

Any suggestions to what i'm missing, or messing up in the command ?
I've been able to run other commands, which didn't need any arguments passed.

Comment: you have to wrap the arguement with " ", --from="2019-02-27 16:22:10"

Comment: @TohidDadashnezhad that worked, if you want to put it in an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters had to be wrapped in " instead of ', so the working command looks like this:

```
php artisan migrate:site:mysite.dk --from="2019-02-27 16:22:10" --to="2019-02-28 23:59:59"
```